# string variable changes to 'null' automaticly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have encountered somthing weird, i ame creating an instance of a class with reflection and this passes a couple parameters, one is the variavle: ipAddress, when creating the instance in the constructor the variable is stored in a field, but as soon as the constructor is complete and i return (in the debugger) to the line where i create the instance i check inside the class and the field 'ipAddress' has changed to null. how is this possible?

This is a part of the class:

```
public class moxa_nport_5110
{
    string instanceName;
    Delegate triggerCallBackMethod;

    private BPUConsole bpuConsole { get; set; }

    TcpIpServer server;
    string ipAddress;

    public moxa_nport_5110(Delegate TriggerCallBackMethod, Delegate Callback, params object[] CtorParam)
    {
        #region Initialize
        triggerCallBackMethod = TriggerCallBackMethod;
        instanceName = (string)CtorParam[0];
        string ipAddress = (string)CtorParam[1];
        int Port = (int)CtorParam[2];
        bpuConsole = new BPUConsole(Callback, instanceName);
        #endregion

        server = new TcpIpServer("10.100.184.140", 8888, false);
        server.OnDataReceived += new TcpIpServer.ReceiveEventHandler(server_OnDataReceived);
        server.OnClientConnected += new TcpIpServer.InfoEventHandler(server_OnClientConnected);
        server.OnClientDisconnected += new TcpIpServer.InfoEventHandler(server_OnClientDisconnected);
        server.OnAbnormalConnectionDisconnect += new TcpIpServer.InfoEventHandler(server_OnAbnormalConnectionDisconnect);
        server.AddClient(ipAddress, 1);
    }

    public void SendData(byte[] Data)
    {
        server.SendData(ipAddress, Data);
    }
```

This is the line where i create the instance:

```
driverInterface = Activator.CreateInstance(driverType, tempParam);  //create an instance of the driver
```

so when i return here, the value of the field ipAddress is null.

EDIT:

Field is thesame value but is not accesed:

[image]

Comment: I ame sorry i have seemed to have found it, i did declare thesame variable inside the constructor as the name of the field, but how is it that in de debugger they both have the ipaddress value this is realy confusing.

Comment: its a debugger error. In your code, type something like "server.AddClient(this.ipAdress). Hovering THAT value and the debugger will show you: `this.ipAdress = null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string ipAddress;

public moxa_nport_5110(Delegate TriggerCallBackMethod, Delegate Callback, params object[] CtorParam)
{
    #region Initialize
    triggerCallBackMethod = TriggerCallBackMethod;
    instanceName = (string)CtorParam[0];
    string ipAddress = (string)CtorParam[1];
}
```

String is a field of the class, so you need to set that value, using `this.`. You are just creating a "new" string called ipAdress, which shadows the field. use `this.ipAdress = ...` instead inside the constructor.

Comment: Yes, i noticed this(stupid mistake :( ), but how is it possible that when debugging they both have the value of the ipaddress?

Comment: @Jeff I dont think they both have the value. the using of the later (unprefixed) ipAdress simple referes to the string with the narrower scope, instead of using the class member. Output it using `this.` and you will see, that one is still empty.

Comment: the initial problem has been solved, but the value of the field is still not clear to me, ive added a screenshot that shows what i mean.

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* variables of the same name in this case, with the second taking precedence due to context: `string ipAddress = (string)CtorParam[1];` sets the variable, but also creates a distinct one - lasting the "lifetime" of the method (constructor, here) - absolutely unrelated to the previous declaration of one with the same name.

In order to set the higher level variable, remove the type prefix from the statement:

```
ipAddress = (string)CtorParam[1];
```

Comment: it is possible to simple have no prefix, that is right. But this is when most of the errors are happening. I would recommend *always* refering class members using the `this.` prefix.

Comment: @dognose That entirely depends, if you need the second thing at all, then yes, if you _mean_ to apply it to the first and therefore must distinguish.